# Behavior from docker-compose command not the same as run in Dockerfile

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose

I have a Django project and I've been struggling with the automation of the static files generation. My project structure has a `docker-compose.yml` file and a `Dockerfile` for every container image.

The docker-compose.yml file for my project:

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    build: ./dispenser
    command: gunicorn -c gunicorn.conf.py dispenser.wsgi
    volumes:
      - ./dispenser:/dispenser
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    restart: on-failure
  nginx:
    build: ./nginx/
    depends_on:
      - web
    command: nginx -g 'daemon off;'
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./dispenser/staticfiles:/var/www/static
    restart: on-failure
```

The Dockerfile for the Django project I'm using:

```
FROM python:3.7.4

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 \
    PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1 \
    WEBAPP_DIR=/dispenser \
    GUNICORN_LOG_DIR=/var/log/gunicorn

WORKDIR $WEBAPP_DIR

RUN mkdir -p $GUNICORN_LOG_DIR \
    mkdir -p $WEBAPP_DIR

ADD pc-requirements.txt $WEBAPP_DIR
RUN pip install -r pc-requirements.txt

ADD . $WEBAPP_DIR

RUN python manage.py makemigrations && \
    python manage.py migrate && \
    python manage.py collectstatic --no-input
```

After several hours of test and research I've found out that running the collectstatic and migrations commands from the Dockerfile doesn't produce the same result as doing it via the `command` argument on the docker-compose.yml file.

If I do it as shown above, when time for running the collectstatic command comes, only the "staticfiles" folder is generated (no files inside it). Also database migrations weren't applied (note that I'm using the default .sqlite3 db). Even though the stdout when creating the container said that migrations were applied and staticfiles generated.

The only workaround I found to make it work was executing bash from the container and then running those commands from there.

But later I've found out that if I specify those commands on the docker-file.yml everything works as expected. Leaving the files as follows:

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    build: ./dispenser
    command: bash -c "python manage.py makemigrations && python manage.py migrate && python manage.py collectstatic --no-input && gunicorn -c gunicorn.conf.py dispenser.wsgi"
    volumes:
      - ./dispenser:/dispenser
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    restart: on-failure
  nginx:
    build: ./nginx/
    depends_on:
      - web
    command: nginx -g 'daemon off;'
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./dispenser/staticfiles:/var/www/static
    restart: on-failure
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.7.4

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 \
    PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1 \
    WEBAPP_DIR=/dispenser \
    GUNICORN_LOG_DIR=/var/log/gunicorn

WORKDIR $WEBAPP_DIR

RUN mkdir -p $GUNICORN_LOG_DIR \
    mkdir -p $WEBAPP_DIR

ADD pc-requirements.txt $WEBAPP_DIR
RUN pip install -r pc-requirements.txt

ADD . $WEBAPP_DIR
```

Can anyone explain me why does this occur? And if is there another way of achieving what I intend without having to specify the commands on the docker-compose.yml file?

Comment: What do the different `manage.py` subcommands do? If they are generating some files, where do they write to?

Comment: The migrate and makemigrations generate a db.sqlite3 file on the same directory and apply the migrations to its tables. And the collectstatic generates a folder "staticfiles" again on the same directory (it's the shared one "/dispenser") and its corresponding files.

Comment: Is the `db.sqlite3` always generated during image build time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you mount a host directory into a container, the contents of host directory shadow the contents of the container.

```
volumes:
      - ./dispenser:/dispenser
```

So when you run your container, the initial contents of `/dispenser` inside container will be the contents of `./dispenser` from host machine. Any content already at `/dispenser` inside the container is shadowed. So the content generated during image build time by the `RUN` instructions inside your Dockerfile will be lost.

In your second approach of using `command` in compose file, you are mounting the volume first and then generating the content and hence it works.

The `command` instruction in Dockerfile is used to override the default command in the Docker image which can be set using `CMD` instruction in Dockerfile. Since you want to use the first approach of running your python script during image build time using `RUN` instructions, you can `RUN` them in a different directory(say /tmp/dispenser) and as part of the `command` in compose or `CMD` in Dockerfile, you can move the generated content from `/tmp/dispenser` to `/dispenser`.